Is it allowed to use web APIs exposed in open-source code?
I often find web projects on GitHub where the author has included their private web API in the code. Is it reasonable to use the author's publicly available web API from the perspective of community rules and consensus in this case?
By “use,” I mean to use in a project where the author's code is forked, modified, and deployed or where the author's original code is deployed directly and used (perhaps on a web page).
Second, is such “use” consistent with open-source licenses? For example, the MIT License and the BSD License. As I understand it, the license gives me the right to use the project's code, which, of course, includes the right to deploy the project and then use it, so it seems reasonable to deploy the unmodified code and then use it.
I searched for related questions on Google but did not find any direct answers; I read the licenses, such as MIT Licenses, BSD Licenses, etc., but the content within the licenses does not seem to answer my questions.
I would especially appreciate answers from members of the open-source community; thanks!

What do you mean when you say that there's a "web API" in the code? Do you mean an API key, or an address to an API, or code invoking an API, or code implementing an API, or something else?

@SophieSwett By “web API,” I mean an API service that is private to the author (in most cases), where the author exposes the address of the API in the open-source code, and everyone can directly request this API, which has no permission settings.

You have to make a distinction between the license to use the client and its source code and the terms and conditions under which you can use a publicly-accessible API on a server. Those two are not related.
Thus, it's perfectly fine to have open-source code that accesses a (possibly configurable) server with a specified API to achieve whatever goal. The license of this client code does not make any statement about under which conditions you may use that API on that specific server, nor that you may use it at all, let alone for free or for a specific purpose. You will need to check the terms and conditions of the server's API by consulting the owner of that server.
The license of the software only allows you to run the software itself (which might as well be modified or configured to access a server with an identical API on another address, which then might be under your own command).
The answer is only slightly different if the server-side code (which provides the API) is licensed under the AGPL. It only mandates that the API's source code is made available to all users of the API. This requirement is not the case for most open source licenses like MIT, BSD, Apache and GPL (regardless of their versions). But even an AGPL license of the server-side code does not give you permission to use the API of that specific server; you might still need permission, which might be granted on the website or might require entering into a contract to use the server's resources. Or, in other words (as clearly phrased by Bart van Ingen Schenau in a comment, thanks for that!): The AGPL (only) gives you the right to obtain the server-side code and to provide a competing service based on that code, but it does not say anything about the terms of service that apply.
The GitHub desktop client itself is an example for this kind of behaviour: the client is open source, and the API is publicly accessible. But you still have to agree to the TOS of Github, which basically is a commercial offering; they are under no obligation to continue granting access to it beyond what is agreed upon in the contract you sign by accepting the TOS.

The AGPL gives you the right to obtain the server-side code and to provide a competing service based on that code, but it does not say anything about the Terms-of-Service that apply.

Ok, thanks. I added your very concise summary to this answer :)

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Obviously, legal considerations aside, you need to

Be considerate: if the author provides a public API then you can use for testing/demos, use it for testing/demos. Don't use it on a site or app that is going to generate tons of traffic and drown their server.
Take into account availability: what happens if the author suddenly decides to take down their API, or change it in a way which makes in incompatible? If you use the API in a service provided to others, you need to be able to rely on the API.

Often they will dictate the terms for using their API, so you can consider that this comes with its own license (a license of use rather than a distribution license), which may be completely unrelated to the license of the software.

indeed. A LOT of private URLs (and even license keys) are exposed accidentally on github and other public repositories. Best you can do when finding one is to contact the owner of the repository and notify them, rather than just assume it'll be fine to use.

Well there’s a couple of aspects to this.
An endpoint that returns the data you desire, returns the data you desire.  But unless you have an agreement with the host, they are under no obligation to continue doing anything with your request, and they can change it to do whatever they want.
Secondly, in the US the CFAA (Computer Fraud and Abuse Act) essentially makes it a federal crime to do ANYTHING with a computer that someone else owns and they don’t like it (and a http request is definitely something). Licenses, terms of service, contracts (including employment contracts) alleviates that somewhat, but don’t completely eliminate the risk.
Up to you as to what kind of risk you are willing to take, but if you’re unsure as to whether they intend to allow it, asking is no worse than just not using it.
